# Can someone help me diagram this very confusing sentence?

Tags: participles, diagramming

Can someone help me diagram this very confusing sentence?

> The vase didn't look like I wanted it to.

That is the sentence.  My teacher said there is a participle, but I can't identify one.

Thanks!

Comment: Your teacher is wrong. There is no participle present. "Wanted" is not a participle, but a past tense form.

Comment: The past participle forms are used to form perfect tenses and passive verb forms.

Comment: @ArchieAzares The example is neither a perfect nor passive construction, but simple past tense where "wanted" is not a past participle, but the past tense form.

Comment: It would be interesting to learn what the teacher thought the participle was in this sentence, and how they tried to explain that.

Answer (score -2):

The participle here would be the word "wanted"

As we all knew, there are two varieties of participle, present and past.

For the reference kindly check this  [link](https://www.englishgrammar.org/present-participles/)

Comment: Ok, I really appreciate the help, but I am unsure how to diagram the sentence too.

Comment: what do you mean by how to diagram the sentence?

Comment: "Wanted" is a past tense form in the OP's example, not a past participle.

Comment: On the link it was said that "Past participles are forms like wanted, broken, started, begun etc. Some verbs have the same past simple and past participle forms. "

Comment: It's like you're saying there is no participle in the sentence "You are fired." .

Comment: The perfect and passive constructions require the presence of the auxiliary verbs, "have" and "be" respectively. There is no auxiliary verb in the OP's example, so it can only be an active voice past tense clause where "wanted" is the past tense form, not a past participle. Your example "You are fired" is a passive clause since it contains the passive auxiliary verb "are" together with the past participle "fired".

Comment: Not everything that looks like a participle is a participle. _I wanted tea_ also contains the form _wanted_ and yet, it contains no participle. Consider _the vase looked bad, but I wanted it to look good_. This answer is probably what the teacher wanted, but that doesn't make it right.